# Android Development: How To Automatically Add Linebreaks When Using setText()?

Tags: android, file, android-edittext, settext

In my app is the ability to read a file.
This works perfectly, but there's a problem.
No line breaks or whatever they are called get added when I append the file's contents to my big EditText, so this:

```
function hmm(){
 echo 'Hello, PHP!';
}
```

would turn into this:

```
function hmm(){ echo 'Hello, PHP!'; }
```

How can I stop this and make it appear in the EditText as it appears in the file?

**UPDATE:
REALLY sorry for wasting your time, I went stupid and didn't think about adding "\n" after the while loop has appended each line.**

Comment: How are you reading in the file?  Are you sure that the newlines are still in the resulting string?

Comment: If you solved your own problem, its helpful if you post your solution as an answer for the next person who runs into the same problem.

Comment: and also to save people who want to help and answer questions from entering this question (as it been already answered and accepted).

Comment: I've not been using StackOverflow.com for long so I've not a clue how I'd do that?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved.**

Basically in the while loop that's used to output each line you need to append a line break (\n) like so:

```
     while (dis.available() != 0) {
      textBox.append(dis.readLine() + "\n");
     }
```

With textBox being an Android EditText.

This will make the EditText look exactly as the text does in the file you selected.